# Compare DataFrames with different rows and columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data in pandas.

[image]

If I find a `+` in `a` column, then I want to compare the data in the column to its right with next row. For example,

```
(b, 12) = 2, compare (c, 13) (e, 13) and (f, 13) (g, 13)
```

If column `c` and `f` are `-` and

```
if (b, 12) = (e, 13) = (g, 13) # that is 2 in the picture.
```

I want to sum all of data, like:

```py
dataframe.same_data.sum()
```

I can't find any method to achieve this.

```
    sum_plus = getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode)).loc[getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode))['15pm'] == '+', '15'].sum()
    sum_minus = getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode)).loc[getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode))['15pm'] == '-', '15'].sum()
    print(sum_plus)

    for i in getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode)).index:
        print('gjk')
        val = getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode)).get_value(i, '15pm')
        print(val)
        if val == '+':
            if val == getattr(self, 'code_{}_data_average'.format(sCode)).get_value(i+1, '91'):
                print('a')
```

Comment: Hi! Please check these links: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Gana - _(g, 13)_? There's no column _g_ in the given data. You'd have to correct that.

Comment: thank u for reply. My English very bad. explain not enough. data is like picture....

Comment: Hi there. I have made some edits to your post to clarify your question and make it easier to read. Please review to make sure that it remains accurate. I now display the image inline, have formatted inline references as `code`, and placed formulas within `code blocks`. I also removed the `row` and `compare` tags as they probably won't help much, and instead added `python`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
That's awesome.
My question is that.
Very very grateful thanks!